# Struts2 taglib needs to include in all files

Tags: struts2

I have a one doubt in struts2. I have a header.jsp page like this:

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %> <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script> 
    </head>
<body>
```

and my home.jsp page like this:

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<s:include value="/WEB-INF/doctor/header.jsp" ></s:include>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1> 
 <s:include value="/WEB-INF/doctor/footer.jsp" ></s:include>
```

and footer.jsp is:

```
</body>
</html>
```

My question is: do I need to include `<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>` tag only in header.jsp or do I need to include it in both header.jsp and home.jsp?

Comment: you need to include it in both sine both are independent jsp and have there own life cycle

Answer (score 0):

If the JSP file is included via a dynamic include mechanism, like `<s:include>` or `<jsp:include>`, yes; the tag library must be declared. JSP files included this way are compiled into their own servlet.

If it's being included statically, you do not need to declare the tag library. Static pages are compiled in to the JSP that included them and operate in the containing page's context.